creating flexible table that automatically goes to next row
I'm trying to create a custom LaTeX environment called FlexibleTable that allows me to input table cells flexibly. The table is designed to have four columns. And I want a command that input next cell or two cells and if necessary goes to next row. E.g. first, second, third, fourth cell goes to first row but fifth will add a row to the table
This is my code:
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{environ}

% Define the table column width
\newlength{\TableColWidth}
\setlength{\TableColWidth}{4.9cm}

% Initialize the counter for columns
\newcounter{flexcol}
\setcounter{flexcol}{0}

% Define the FlexibleTable environment
\NewEnviron{FlexibleTable}{%
    \setcounter{flexcol}{0}%
    \begin{tabular}{| p{\TableColWidth} | p{\TableColWidth} | p{\TableColWidth} | p{\TableColWidth} |}
    \hline
    \BODY
    \ifnum\value{flexcol}>0
        % Calculate the number of empty cells needed to complete the row
        \multicolumn{\the\numexpr4-\value{flexcol}\relax}{c|}{} \\ \hline
    \fi
    \end{tabular}
}

% Define the FlexCell command using \newcommand
\newcommand{\FlexCell}[1]{%
    #1%
    \stepcounter{flexcol}%
    \ifnum\value{flexcol}=4
        \\ \hline
        \setcounter{flexcol}{0}%
    \else
        &%
    \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{FlexibleTable}
    \FlexCell{\textbf{Header 1}}
    \FlexCell{\textbf{Header 2}}
    \FlexCell{\textbf{Header 3}}
    \FlexCell{\textbf{Header 4}}
    
    \FlexCell{Row 1, Cell 1}
    \FlexCell{Row 1, Cell 2}
    \FlexCell{Row 1, Cell 3}
    \FlexCell{Row 1, Cell 4}
    
    \FlexCell{Row 2, Cell 1} % This will create an incomplete row
\end{FlexibleTable}

\end{document}

I get following error:
! Incomplete \ifnum; all text was ignored after line 51.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.51 \end{FlexibleTable}


Can anyone guide me how to solve this?

Welcome to TeX.SX!

With expl3. We define \FlexCell to just add an item to a sequence. After this is completed, the sequence is extended with empty cells in order to get a multiple of 4.
Finally the sequence is mapped: the item is delivered and, if the index is a multiple of 4, we also issue \\ \hline, otherwise &.
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Define the FlexibleTable environment
\NewDocumentEnvironment{FlexibleTable}{m+b}
 {
  \zakirov_flextab:nn {#1} {#2}
 }{}

% Define the FlexCell command
\NewDocumentCommand{\FlexCell}{m}
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_zakirov_flextab_seq {#1}
 }

\seq_new:N \l_zakirov_flextab_seq

% the main function
\cs_new_protected:Nn \zakirov_flextab:nn
 {
  % start the tabular
  \begin{tabular}{ | *{4}{p{#1}|} }
  \hline
  % populate the sequence
  #2
  % ensure that the number of cells is a multiple of 4
  \int_compare:nF { \int_mod:nn {\seq_count:N \l_zakirov_flextab_seq} {4} == 0 }
   {% we need to add some dummy cells
    \prg_replicate:nn { 4 - \int_mod:nn {\seq_count:N \l_zakirov_flextab_seq} {4} }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l_zakirov_flextab_seq {}
     }
   }
  % deliver the contents: at multiples of 4 issue '\\ \hline', else `&'
  \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \l_zakirov_flextab_seq \__zakirov_flextab_cell:nn
  % end
  \end{tabular}
}

% the auxiliary command
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__zakirov_flextab_cell:nn
 {% #1 = current index, #2 = item
  #2 \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn {#1}{4} == 0 } { \\ \hline } { & }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}

\begin{FlexibleTable}{2.5cm}
    \FlexCell{\textbf{Header 1}}
    \FlexCell{\textbf{Header 2}}
    \FlexCell{\textbf{Header 3}}
    \FlexCell{\textbf{Header 4}}
    
    \FlexCell{Row 1, Cell 1}
    \FlexCell{Row 1, Cell 2}
    \FlexCell{Row 1, Cell 3}
    \FlexCell{Row 1, Cell 4}
    
    \FlexCell{Row 2, Cell 1} % This will create an incomplete row
\end{FlexibleTable}

\end{document}



Usually (or at least often) such layouts are better considered as a paragraph of flowing boxes rather than a tabular structure.

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{FlexibleTable}{}{\begin{flushleft}}{\end{flushleft}}

% Define the FlexCell command using \newcommand
\newcommand{\FlexCell}[1]{\hfil\makebox[.24\textwidth][l]{#1}\hfil}


\begin{document}

\begin{FlexibleTable}
    \FlexCell{\textbf{Header 1}}
    \FlexCell{\textbf{Header 2}}
    \FlexCell{\textbf{Header 3}}
    \FlexCell{\textbf{Header 4}}    
    \FlexCell{Row 1, Cell 1}
    \FlexCell{Row 1, Cell 2}
    \FlexCell{Row 1, Cell 3}
    \FlexCell{Row 1, Cell 4}   
    \FlexCell{Row 2, Cell 1} % This will create an incomplete row
\end{FlexibleTable}

\end{document}


Thanks a lot. I like it  - it is neat and simple. But need a table :(

https://ctan.org/pkg/nox

Maybe you like to try this:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \parindent=0pt
           \newcount\columns
           \columns=1
           \newcount\floors
           \floors=1%floor is just another name for a line
           \newcount\limit
           \newcount\cells
           \cells=1
           \newcount\linelimit
           \linelimit=1
           \newcount\tables
           \tables=0
           \newdimen\cellwidth
    \def\cellempty{-}
    \def\condition[#1,#2,#3,#4]#5{
    \ifnum\the\tables=#1\ifnum\the\floors=#2\ifnum\the\columns=#3\hsize=\cellwidth\leavevmode\ignorespaces #5\vskip\baselineskip\fi\fi\fi}
    \def\cell{\vtop{\conditionals}\hskip4pt\global\advance\cells by 1}
    \def\floor{\vskip0.1\baselineskip\advance\floors by 1\hbox{\loop\cell \advance\columns  by 1\ifnum \columns<\limit\repeat}\columns=1}
    \def\newtable[#1,#2,#3]{\vskip\baselineskip Table \tables =#1 \the\tables\linelimit=#2\limit=#3\cellwidth=\hsize\divide\cellwidth by \limit\floors=0\loop\floor \ifnum\the\floors<#2\repeat}
    \def\conditionals{
    \condition [1,1,1,0]{Test}
    \condition [1,1,2,0]{Second}
    \condition [1,1,3,0]{Third}
    \condition [1,1,4,0]{Forth}
    \condition [1,2,1,0]{Fifth}
    \condition [1,2,2,0]{Sixth}
    \condition [1,2,3,0]{Seventh}
    \condition [1,2,4,0]{Eighth}
    }
    \begin{document}
      Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.
    \newtable[1,5,4] %lines and columns
    
     Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.
     \end{document}

